# How to skip phoronix-test-suite inital questions

Tags: benchmarking, non-interactive

I would like to use phoronix-test-suite to benchmark cloud instances of different providers.

Nevertheless automation seems to get hang, because phoronix-test-suites asks three initial questions to accept license agreement, whether to upload benchmark results to openbenchmarking and so on.

I know that the batch-run can be preconfigured using the user-config.xml file. But this seems not sufficient to run benchmarks non-interactively the first time.

Phoronix-test-suite still asks its initial questions which prevents automatic benchmarking of

Can anybody help? Is there another file which phoronix-test-suite needs to not ask its initial questions?

Answer (score 3):

running "phoronix-test-suite enterprise-setup" on PTS 5.6+ is another way to avoid the initial setup questions.

Answer (score 0):

After digging in the sources I discovered environment variable - PTS_SILENT_MODE. Just set it to 1.

Example: 
On *fresh install* when I run

```
PTS_SILENT_MODE=1 phoronix-test-suite benchmark pts/openssl-1.9.0
```

Then 3 initial questions are not asked

Comment: Thanks. Cool tip. I figured out this variant here using the 'yes' command. yes | phoronix-test-suites ... This will answer all questions with 'yes' and phoronix will run non-interactively. Nevertheless all collected benchmark data will be provided to openbenchmarking.org. Does the PTS_SILENT_MODE do the same?

Answer (score 0):

Tested on Phoronix Test Suite 10.8.4 installed as mentioned at: https://askubuntu.com/questions/634513/cpu-benchmarking-utility-for-linux/899130 the best I could find was first to run:

```
phoronix-test-suite batch-setup
```

and then interactively answer:

```
    Save test results when in batch mode (Y/n): y
    Open the web browser automatically when in batch mode (y/N): n
    Auto upload the results to OpenBenchmarking.org (Y/n): n
    Prompt for test identifier (Y/n): n
    Prompt for test description (Y/n): n
    Prompt for saved results file-name (Y/n): n
    Run all test options (Y/n): n
```

This step can also be fully automated with:

```
printf 'y\nn\nn\nn\nn\nn\nn\n' | phoronix-test-suite batch-setup
```

These settings are stored under `~/.phoronix-test-suite/user-config.xml`:

```xml
<PhoronixTestSuite>
  <Options>
    <BatchMode>
      <SaveResults>TRUE</SaveResults>
      <OpenBrowser>FALSE</OpenBrowser>
      <UploadResults>FALSE</UploadResults>
      <PromptForTestIdentifier>FALSE</PromptForTestIdentifier>
      <PromptForTestDescription>FALSE</PromptForTestDescription>
      <PromptSaveName>FALSE</PromptSaveName>
      <RunAllTestCombinations>FALSE</RunAllTestCombinations>
      <Configured>TRUE</Configured>
    </BatchMode>
```

so seding that file would be another option.

From then on, when you use `batch-run` to run instead of `run`, the only thing it will ask when trying to run a benchmark such as `pts/stress-ng`:

```
phoronix-test-suite batch-run pts/stress-ng
```

is which configuration to run:

```
Stress-NG 0.16.04:
    pts/stress-ng-1.11.0
    System Test Configuration
        1:  CPU Stress
        2:  Crypto
        3:  Memory Copying
...
        40: Test All Options
        ** Multiple items can be selected, delimit by a comma. **
        Test:
```

which we can once again automate with a pipe e.g.:

```
echo 1 | phoronix-test-suite batch-run pts/stress-ng
```

to select option 1, `1:  CPU Stress`.